# Why does border thickness change with color of button (blue gets 2px border)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, border

I'm working on a game, and for some reason the border thickness changes depending on what color the button is. This problem didn't happen until I put a background image on the app, so I'm not sure what's causing it. I took a couple screenshots to show what I mean. For some reason, the border thickness changes to 2px instead of 1px when the button that is being bordered is blue.

In addition, there are some problems with the borders on the control buttons. By control buttons, I mean the 6 buttons up top that are in the order of Red, Blue, Brown, Green, Purple, and Yellow.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: Screenshot #1][image: Screenshot #2]

I create the borders by putting a button in the background which starts at x-1,y-1 and has a width of width+2 and height of height+2. Here is a piece of code to give you an idea:

```
 UIButton *borderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 borderButton.frame = CGRectMake((controlX-1), (controlY-1), 42, 32);
 borderButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.view addSubview:borderButton];

 UIButton *controlButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [controlButton addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(doMove:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 controlButton.frame = CGRectMake(controlX, controlY, 40, 30);
 controlButton.tag = 500 + i;
 tmpColor = [self.colors objectAtIndex:i];
 controlButton.backgroundColor = tmpColor;
 [self.view addSubview:controlButton];
```

This code is taken from a loop, where controlX and controlY give x/y values for where the control buttons should start.

If anyone knows how to fix this I would greatly appreciate it. If I am going about borders in the wrong way and there is an easier and less problematic way of achieving the same look, I would be willing to do that as well, because there wouldn't be much code to change on my end. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this irritating UI glitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement custom button with border is to use the button's layer:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
UIButton *controlButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [controlButton addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(doMove:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 controlButton.frame = CGRectMake(controlX, controlY, 40, 30);
 controlButton.tag = 500 + i;

 // Set layer properties
 controlButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
 controlButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 controlButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0; // if you want rounded corners...

 tmpColor = [self.colors objectAtIndex:i];
 controlButton.backgroundColor = tmpColor;
 [self.view addSubview:controlButton];
```

You may also need to check that button and other elements (like labels) are located at integral coordinates to avoid blurred images. To correct the coordinates use [CGRectIntegral](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntegral)

P.S. For complex animations/game logic it is better to use frameworks like [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org)

Comment: The problem still persists in that the borders look off on the buttons. Here is a screenshot after I implemented your code: http://mdl.fm/f/b3.png You see how the blue one looks weird? The red one does too, but the blue is the most noticeable. Is there an inherent issue with borders on blue buttons in iOS? Thanks for the suggestion though, +1 on your response because that is a much better way to handle borders than what I had done.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You can play with borderWidth/cornerRadius (increase borderWidth?). But the best option is to use custom background image (or use [stretchable image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:))

Comment: Thanks for the help, I played around with it, and I found that the best solution was just to change the color of the buttons. I made them a little bit lighter and the problem is not nearly as noticeable now.